# weblogic - get http/https connections count

Tags: http, https, connection, weblogic

I am looking for way to **get http/https** (both combined) **current active connections count**.
I am using Weblogic server with multiple Webapps.

Usage of count of connections is to send request on 100 connections established on server so other app remind me. when 100 up connection established at time.

Any way to get http/https connections.
Or I need to go with linux commands?

Answer (score 0):

This information should be exposed via JMX. You can use JMC (Java Mission Control) which comes with JDK and connect via JMX on your application.

Or, from Linux you can use something like `netstat -tnp| egrep ':80|443'|wc -l`